# How to sum a list of numbers in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

This works:

```
(+ 1 2 3)
6
```

This doesn't work:

```
(+ '(1 2 3))
```

This works if '`cl-*`' is loaded:

```
(reduce '+ '(1 2 3))
6
```

If `reduce` were always available I could write:

```
(defun sum (L)
  (reduce '+ L))

(sum '(1 2 3))
6
```

What is the best practice for defining functions such as `sum`?

Comment: Please do not change the question, open a new one.

Comment: I've rollbacked the question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
(apply '+ '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've thought that I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 3):

If you manipulate lists and write functional code in Emacs, install [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library. Then you could use its [`-sum`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) function:

```
(-sum '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; => 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Linearly recursive function (sum L)

```
;;
;; sum
;;
(defun sum(list)    
    (if (null list)
        0

        (+ 
            (first list) 
            (sum (rest list))
        )   
    )   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom function to calculate the sum of a list passed to it.

```
(defun sum (lst) (format t "The sum is ~s~%" (write-to-string (apply '+ lst))) 
EVAL: (sum '(1 4 6 4))
-> The sum is "15"
```

Answer (score -1):

This ought to do the trick:

```
(defun sum-list (list)
  (if list
      (+ (car list) (sum-list (cdr list)))
    0))
```

[[source]](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs19/cl_16.html)

Edit: [Here is another good link](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/emacs-lisp-intro_8.html) that explains `car` and `cdr` - basically they are functions that allow you to grab the first element of a list and retrieve a new list sans the first item.

Comment: Recursion is *bad* in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing exactly that.

Comment: Most of the time, you should be able to use reduce and the varieties of map operations instead of explicitly handling cars and cdrs.

Comment: Because Emacs Lisp does not do tail call optimization.  What’s more your sum-list recursion is *not* in tail position.

Comment: Good to know! I am still learning all the ins and outs of Lisp myself.

Comment: Then you have an exercice: rewrite your function so that it runs in constant space.

Comment: Yikes! I will see what I can do :)

Comment: @kmkaplan: Shouldn't `if` be short-circuited? In that case `sum-list` is in a tail-recursion position, isn't it?

Comment: The if is not the problem.  The problem is the (+ ... (sum-list ...)).  This creates a new frame so that computation of the + function can be done once sum-list returns.

Comment: @kmkaplan: (defun sum-iter (L total) (if L (sum-iter (cdr L) (+ (car L) total)) total)) ? (sum-iter '(1 2 3) 0) -> 6

Comment: Yes.  But remember not to do it with Emacs Lisp, just with Lisps that give you tail call optimization.

Answer (score -2):

`(eval (cons '+ '(1 2 3)))` -- though not as good as 'reduce'

Comment: There's no need for eval.  Apply does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it was just to show that it could be done in this way as well.

Answer (score -2):

(insert (number-to-string (apply '+ '(1 2 3))))