# Emacs Lisp: How to sum odd numbers in a list?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to find elisp's analog of:

```
sum(n for n in numbers if n % 2) # Python
numbers.select { |n| n % 2 != 0 }.inject { |a, b| a + b } # Ruby
```

Imperative way:

```
(defun oddp (number)
  (not (= (mod number 2) 0)))

(defun sum-odd-with-dolist (list)
  (let ((acc 0))
    (dolist (item list acc)
      (if (oddp item)
          (setq acc (+ item acc))))))
```

From [Porting Common Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Porting-Common-Lisp.html):

```
(defun sum-odd-with-dolist-incr (list)
  (let ((total 0)) 
    (dolist (item list) 
      (if (oddp item)
          (incf total item))) 
      total))
```

Using   '`cl-*`' `loop`:

```
(defun sum-odd-with-loop (list)
  (loop for x in list if (oddp x) sum x))

(sum-odd-with-loop '(1 2 3))
4
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do it (that does not require `cl-*` packages)?

#### Related:

> [How to sum a list of numbers in Emacs Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590579/how-to-sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-emacs-lisp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(apply '+ (delq nil (mapcar (lambda (x) (and (= 1 (% x 2)) x)) '(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

Comment: Does it copy the whole list if the first argument is even?

Comment: There is no arguments, i've wrote just an expression. And what it does is this: it filters the list and then applies '+. Filtering constructs new list, indeed. Anyway, the result does not rely on first argument being even or odd. So i'm not sure i understand your question right..

Comment: s/argument/1st element of the list/. Documentation for `delq` says that it can't delete the first element in-place (or I've misunderstood something).

Comment: I was completely wrong about delq, it may modify the list in case "object" is not the first element. So, would remq be proper, as it creates a new list?

Comment: Although, mapcar constructs new list just for delq/remq, so original list stays intact.

Comment: So, yeah, anyway, thanks for pointing out the modifying effect of delq :)

Answer (score 14):

The idiomatic way to do it is to use the functions and macros in the `cl` packages. They come as standard with Emacs Lisp and there's nothing wrong with using them.

I doubt you'll find a way to do it that's as terse and clear as

```
(loop for x in list if (oddp x) sum x)
```

There are more functional ways to do it, such as

```
(apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'oddp list))
```

but this uses `remove-if-not` which is from the `cl-seq` package.  You could write out a loop by hand:

```
(let ((sum 0)) (dolist (x list sum) (when (oddp x) (incf sum x))))
```

but this uses `dolist` and `incf` which are both in the `cl-macs` package. Basically you can't escape the `cl` package: `oddp` itself is a `cl` function!

My best effort using absolutely no `cl` facilities is this:

```
(apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (* x (mod x 2))) list))
```

but it would absurd to use this in practice instead of the `(loop ...)` version.

Comment: Thanks. I like variant w/ remove-if-not despite it is a CL (though works without #). What is the online reference for such functions, is it http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html ?

Comment: It's http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/cl.html — but if you have Emacs, you may already have the cl manual; try typing C-h i m cl RET.

Comment: Common Lisp itself has a HyperSpec, which is online in various places, including here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Gareth Rees's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592016/596361), but if you use functional programming and data manipulation heavily in your code, i strongly recommend installing Magnar Sveen's [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list API. It has ridiculous amount of functions for writing concise and elegant functional code. Incidentally, it itself is written without `cl` library. Summing up odd numbers in a list would then be:

```
(-sum (--filter (= (mod it 2) 1) '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

[`-sum`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-sum-list) is short for `(-reduce '+ xs)`. Functions starting with 2 hyphens are [anaphoric macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro), they expose a temporary variable. For example, here instead of passing `(lambda (x) (= (mod x 2) 1))` to [`--filter`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-filter-pred-list) we simply write `(= (mod it 2) 1)`, where `it` is used for a local variable.

Comment: A more concise way: `(-sum (-filter #'oddp '(1 2 3 4 5)))`, or my favourite, using threading macros: `(->> '(1 2 3 4 5) (-filter #'oddp) (-sum))`.

Comment: Good catch! But `oddp` is from `cl.el`, so if for some reason you don't use it in your code, you have to use `(= (mod it 2) 1)`. Do you mind if I integrate your comment in my answer (with attribution)?

Comment: No problem, feel free to integrate with or without attribution.